# Java interface to compare various data types

Tags: java, comparison, comparable

I need to have an interface that will allow this to work for all data types if implemented with generics. Something to this effect.

```
  if (myIter.myDataType < SearchDataType){
      return myIter;
  }
```

or

```
  if (myIter.compareTo(SearchDataType)){
      return myIter;
  }
```

needs to work with integers, char, strings and even Boolean if possible.
I'm new to java so I'm not aware of something that does this.

Comment: are `myDataType` the same as `SearchDataType` or is myIter always the same type or are they 2 random types?

Comment: you can do something similar with enums - take a look at the [ordinal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) function

Comment: Are you looking for... `Comparable`?

Comment: @fdsa , yes they will be the same data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
class MyDataType<T extends Comparable<T>>{
    T data;

    public MyDataType(T _data){
        data = _data;
    }
}
```

Feels like a homework question. ;)